# Null Pointer Exception At android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java)

Tags: android, sqlite

Background - I'm trying to retrieve a list of auctions filtered by State.  I'm trying to retrieve Auction Date and Name of Auction.

I pick up the State name from a listview - the state value is being passed correctly (I've commented out the name of function that builds the State list and used Toast to verify a good value)

My problem is occurring in the fillAuctionsList(String editAuctionState);

```
public void fillAuctionsList(String editAuctionState){
    //sql Query - editAuctionState is the State selected

    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    //set the table to the Auction
    queryBuilder.setTables(Auctions.AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME);

    // build the return columns for my listview
    String asColumnsToReturn[]= {
            Auctions.AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME + "." + Auctions.AUCTIONS_AUCTION_NAME,
            Auctions.AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME + "." + Auctions.AUCTIONS_DATE,
            Auctions.AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME + "." + Auctions.AUCTIONS_STATE,
            Auctions.AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME + "." + Auctions._ID}; 
    //end of build columns to return

    //build the where statement based on the Auction State
    String howToFilter[]={editAuctionState};

    //build the cursor

    mCursor = queryBuilder.query(mDB, asColumnsToReturn, Auctions.AUCTIONS_STATE + "=?", howToFilter,null, null, null);

    //manage the cursor
    startManagingCursor(mCursor);

    int HowManyRecords = mCursor.getCount();
    if(HowManyRecords==0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Records Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
```

More cursor code after this.

I get the Null Pointer Exception error at the querybuilder statement - app never seems to get to the code for a count of the number of records.

Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved....

I had a 'duh' moment and had not bothered to actually open the database.